# How to remove the nuget package so that they are not uploaded to gitlab or github?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, github, gitlab

How to remove the nuget package from .NET projects so that they are not uploaded to gitlab or github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a git .ignore file that includes the those files and resources you wish to exclude.

[Ignoring files with .ignore file](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/ignoring-files)

If you have problems creating your own .ignore file you can use this online generator.

[Git Ignore website](https://www.gitignore.io/)

Just type your programming language, for instance csharp, and hit the create button, a ignore file is generated for you.